# How to create a variable which stores a function result within another function in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

I’m a big noob.

`Function B` is part of the body of `function A`.

Inside a `function A`, **I would like to create a variable to store the `function B` result** in postgresql, and **to use that result as a comparison argument just after**, still inside `function A`.

I rode documentation and tried 2 approaches, but can’t get what I would like:

The variable I want to create is named `remaining_time` in the example below.

1st try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remaining_period(start DATE, months INT) RETURNS INTERVAL AS
$$
DECLARE
  remaining_time = SELECT AGE((start + (months || ' months')::INTERVAL)::DATE, NOW()::DATE);
BEGIN
  CASE WHEN remaining_time > INTERVAL '0 day' THEN remaining_time
       ELSE INTERVAL '0 day'
END
$$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

2nd try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remaining_period(start DATE, months INT) RETURNS INTERVAL AS
$$
  SELECT AGE((start + (months || ' months')::INTERVAL)::DATE, NOW()::DATE) AS remaining_time;
  CASE WHEN remaining_time > INTERVAL '0 day' THEN remaining_time
       ELSE INTERVAL '0 day'
$$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Comment: You can't have variables in plain SQL functions - they are just SQL. You probably want to read the manual section covering pl/pgsql https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html

Answer (score 0):

As indicated you cannot use named variable within a SQL function. However, it is not necessary. You have 2 options: define the "variable" within SQL through a cte or sub-query or just use the calculation directly. So (See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/TSqcgqF4))

```
create or replace function remaining_period(start date, months int)
   returns interval 
  language sql 
  immutable strict
as $$
  with remaining(tm) as 
       (select age((start + (months || ' months')::interval)::date, now()::date) as remaining_time)
  select case when tm > interval '0 day' 
              then tm
              else interval '0 day'
         end
    from remaining;
$$;

create or replace function remaining_period2(start date, months int)
   returns interval 
  language sql 
  immutable strict
as $$
    select greatest( age((start + (months || ' months')::interval)::date, now()::date)
                   , interval '0 day'
                   ); 
$$;
```